# How to create aab (bundle) via Fastlane?

Tags: android, google-play, react-native, fastlane

I want to create `aab` (bundle) via `Fastlane`, but so far I was able to create only `apk`, here is my `lane` now, how to create aab?

```
 lane :beta do
    store_password = prompt(text: "Signing Store Password: ", secure_text: true)
    key_password = prompt(text: "Alias Key Password: ", secure_text: true)
    releaseFilePath = File.join(Dir.pwd, "..", "my-release-key.keystore")
    gradle(task: 'clean')
    gradle(
      task: 'assemble',
      build_type: 'Release',
      print_command: false,
      properties: {
        "android.injected.signing.store.file" => releaseFilePath,
        "android.injected.signing.store.password" => store_password,
        "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "my-key-alias",
        "android.injected.signing.key.password" => key_password,
      }
    )
    upload_to_play_store(
      track: 'internal'
    )
```

Comment: Just change task from `assemble` to `bundle` as mention in `https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gradle/`

Comment: Thanks, I missed that when was reading documentation!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Changing `task` from `assemble` to `bundle`, solved my issue!

Answer (score 3):

Create signed Android App Bundle(aab) Release file, next sent to Google Play and automatically make a Release to production.

Run: **fastlane build_aab --verbose**

```
  lane :build_aab do
      gradle(task: 'clean')
      gradle(
        task: 'bundle',
        build_type: 'Release',
        print_command: true,
        properties: {
          "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "loca_file_system/unsigloenguerra.jks",
          "android.injected.signing.store.password" => "Un$1986nWa_",
          "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "key0",
          "android.injected.signing.key.password" => "Un$1986nWa_",
        }
      )
      upload_to_play_store(
          track:'production',
          skip_upload_metadata: true,
          skip_upload_images: true,
          skip_upload_screenshots: true)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Before try to build the aab file don't forget to run
**"fastlane supply init"** and make the setting up your Google Developers Service Account if not is impossible to connect with google play console.